# How to test a component with a nested container with React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, redux, jsdom

Due to the complexity of the application I am working on I have decided on using a nested redux container rather than passing an action as a prop down to the child components. However, this has proved to be problematic for unit testing when rendering the `OuterContainer` with [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) in combination with `mocha`, `chai` and `sinon`.

Here is a contrived example of the view structure:

```
<OuterContainer>
  <div>
    <InnerContainer />
  </div>
</OuterContainer>
```

where `OuterContainer` & `InnerContainer` are wrapped with connect. e.g.:

`export connect(<mapStateToProps>)(<Component>)`

When running tests the error I am getting is:

`` Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Component)". Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Component)". ``

Is there a way to unwrap or stub the `InnerContainer` for unit testing without having to use shallow rendering?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wrap your component in `<Provider>` when testing. It’s up to you whether to supply a real store or a mock with `{ dispatch, getState, subscribe }` to it. Wrapping the outermost component in `<Provider store={store}>` will also make the store available to the child components at any level of nesting—just like in the app itself.

```
const store = createStore(reducer) // can also be a mock
ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <OuterContainer />
  </Provider>
)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the advice. Giving this a go now :)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again @DanAbramov !

Comment: @dan-abramov: this works. However, it's not really a unit test anymore. Enzyme has `shallow`, but it still goes deep with a connected child component. Do you have any idea if it's possible to just test if `<InnerContainer />` is there without rendering it?

Comment: I echo @publicJorn concern. I like this solution myself, but it makes the tests way more complex than they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to export both the component to be connected and the container. The container as default, of course.

```
export const Comp = (props) => (<p>Whatever</p>)
export default connect(...)(Comp)
```

Hence, you can unit test `Comp`.

Comment: But this defeats the purpose of testing the component with complete Redux linkage. Won't it?

Comment: @shobhit1 but then you're testing your component and `connect` which is already tested by `react-redux`. Is not bad, neither good. You're just overtesting then.

Comment: This will not work if, as in the question, `Comp` itself imports and uses another container. The subcontainer will then expect `store` to be present, and the test will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your problem is, but I'm sure this will probably help a few people out there looking at this feed.

I had the same error and it was a simple fix:

I had forgotten to pass my  component my store object in my entry file (using webpack).

I just added an attribute to the Root component "store={store}" see below:

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      const store = configureStore();
       ReactDOM.render(<Root store={store} />, 
     document.getElementById('content'));
    });
```

This was my root file code for reference as well:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import App from './app';

    const Root = ({ store }) => (
     <Provider store={ store }>
        <App />
     </Provider>
    );
```

export default Root;

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Mock the `Provider` component to return the child component.

Add this before `describe()`.

`jest.mock('Provider', () => ({children}) => children);`